# Gif not working in outlook leatest version

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I wrote code like below.

<%= image_tag 'image.gif' %>

```
    or
```

<%= image_tag 'Added s3 Gif' %>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the below steps work well.

Windows 10

Start-> Settings-> Ease of Access-> Display-> Show animations in Windows

Windows 11

Start-> Settings-> Accessibility-> Visual effects-> Animation effects

In case not working gif reinstall the Microsoft outlook then working well.

Comment: Double click on the email (Action ->View Browser)